# "runas" command executes successfully but desired output is not achieved

Tags: cmd, runas

I am executing a runas command in cmd which is to create a new user as an Administrator and it is executing successfully without giving any errors but the user is not getting created.

The command which I am using is `runas /user:Administrator "cmd /c net user /add username password"`

Answer (score 0):

Your `/user:Administrator` argument has the wrong format.

It should be in the form:

```
/user:<AdministratorAccountName>@<ComputerName>
/user:<ComputerName>\<AdministratorAccountName>
/user:<AdministratorAccountName>@<DomainName>
/user:<DomainName>\<AdministratorAccountName>
```

---

Source [RUNAS - Execute a program under a different user account](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)

> **Syntax** ...
>
> ```
>  RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred] ] /smartcard [/user:UserName] program
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Key**
>
> ...
>
> ```
> /user UserName in the form USER@DOMAIN or DOMAIN\USER
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> Runas /env /user:SS64Dom\jDoe "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"
> ```

See Technet [Runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx) for more information.

---

**"I tried `runas /profile /user:yogi\Administrator "cmd net user /add username password"` but its still not working**

1. You don't need `cmd` in there.
2. The format of your `net user...` command is incorrect. The `/add` should be after `username password`

Try the following:

```
runas /profile /user:yogi\Administrator "cmd net user username password /add"
```

---

Source [Net user](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/librar/cc771865.aspx)

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> net user [<UserName> {<Password> | *} [<Options>]] [/domain]
> net user [<UserName> {<Password> | *} /add [<Options>] [/domain]]
> net user [<UserName> [/delete] [/domain]]
> ```

Comment: I tried running as `runas /profile /user:yogi\Administrator "cmd net user /add username password"` but its still not working.. :(

Comment: @yjs The format of your `net user` command is incorrect. Answer updated.

Comment: thanks for the rply.. I tried the code after editing it.. still not working. I even tried starting a new cmd as a user who is an Admin by using `runas /profile /user:yogi\ADMINUSER "cmd"` and then manually typed `net user username passwd /add` command in the new cmd then it gave me an error System error 5 has occured. Access is denied. Any idea why am I getting this error??

Comment: For some reason it thinks you are **not** an adminstrator. I've no idea why. Google "System error 5" for some possibilities for your own investigation.